# Turning multi-column data into rows of triplets with a type column whose values are based on the original columns names

Tags: google-sheets

I have data in a Google Sheet that looks like this:

```
Entity  A   B   C

foo     42  27  13
bar     67  17  94
```

I'd like to turn it into this:

```
Entity  Type  Value

foo     A     42
foo     B     27
foo     C     13
bar     A     67
bar     B     17
bar     C     94
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the simplest, but this works for me

```
=ArrayFormula(split(transpose(split(textjoin(";",true,A2:A3&","&B1:D1&","&B2:D3),";")),","))
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I used comma as a separator between columns and a semicolon as a separator between rows because they're used in Google Sheets & Excel when setting up array constants, but you can choose any pair of characters to avoid clashes with the set of characters used in your data e.g.

```
=ArrayFormula(split(transpose(split(textjoin("§",true,A2:A3&"¶"&B1:D1&"¶"&B2:D3),"§")),"¶"))
```

Comment: Wow, that almost works! The only minor hitch is that some of the values for "Entity" actually contain commas in them so I think those need to be handled somehow.

Comment: Maybe a comma wasn't such a good choice of separator, will have a look at it. Do the entities contain any characters like | # etc?

Comment: No, they don't have anything that weird in them. That character you used here now should do.